# Вот такие вот ошибки:

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class MyClass{
    public :
    void SetArr(char arr[37]){
            for(int i = 0; i!=37; i++){   // Передача массива arr из main в массив СlasArr в классе
    9           *ClasArr[i] = arr [i];
            }
    }
    void GetArr(char *ClasArr[37]){
            for(int i = 0; i!=37; i++){  // Вывод из массива ClasArr
                cout << *ClasArr[i];
            }
    }
    private:
        char ClasArr[37];

    };
    int main()
    {
        char hand[2];  
        char arr [37];
        int i=0;
        while ( hand != "0"){
            cin >> hand;            // Ввод массива пока не введён 0
    30      arr[i] = hand;
            i++;
        }
    33  Myclass object;
    34  object.SetArr(char *arr[37]);  
    35  object.GetArr(char *ClasArr[37]);
        return 0;
    }

------
```

И этот код возвращает следующие ошибки:

```c++
        ||=== Build: Release in temp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| 
        9|error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')| 
        30|error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]|
        33|error: 'Myclass' was not declared in this scope|
        34|error: 'object' was not declared in this scope|
        34|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'|
        35|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'|
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: А в чем, собственно, суть вопроса?

Comment: абсолютно логичные ошибки. Пытаетесь использовать ClasArr, а объявить забыли.

Comment: Таки да, но после обьявления единственное что меняеться это ошибка в  9 строке на 9|error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'char')|
А суть вопроса в том что запутался с указателями и символами.

Comment: я даже не знаю, зачем в 9 строке звездочка

Comment: Ссылка на массив в private, его же из вне нельзя изменять, разве нет?

Comment: object.SetArr(char *arr[37]);  вы наверное хотели написать object.SetArr(arr), вообще жуткая дичь какая-то написана. В функцию надо передавать непосредственно массив, который вы уже создали. В вашем случае arr. Указание типа char в вызове функции не нужно. Сигнатура вроде  void SetArr(char arr[37]) конечно имеет место быть, но надо понимать, что по сути будет передан указатель на массив, его размер никакой роли не играет. Не ошибка, но тож дичь немного

Comment: Плюс у вас в 33 строчке Myclass вместо MyClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче кровь из глаз, конечно, но вот маленько поправил

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass 
{
public:
    void SetArr(char* _array) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 37; i++) 
            m_class_arr[i] = _array[i];
    }
    void GetArr() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 37; i++) 
            std::cout << m_class_arr[i];
    }
private:
    char m_class_arr[37];

};

int main()
{
    char hand =' ';
    char arr[37];
    int i = 0;

    while (hand != '0') 
    {
        std::cin >> hand;
        arr[i] = hand;
        i++;
    }
    MyClass object;
    object.SetArr(arr);
    object.GetArr();
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```